# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string despite of using to_date function

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, oracle11g

Facing this error on EXCEL VBA Module. On Oracle 11g interface it runs well.

```
select 
        "schema_name", "table_name", "bundle_name", "text_file", "sequence_no", 
                    lastupdateapplied, "next_sat_date","prev_sat_date", TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'),
        CASE 
                WHEN ("schema_name"='EDM_V1' OR "schema_name"='FF_V3' OR "schema_name"='SYM_V1') and 
                            ("next_sat_date"-lastupdateapplied<=0 OR 
                            lastupdateapplied-"prev_sat_date">=0) 
                then 'EVERYTHING LOOKS OK HERE.'
                WHEN  ("schema_name"='FP_V2' OR "schema_name"='FE_V4' OR "schema_name"='REF_V2') and 
                            (lastupdateapplied - TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY') =0)
                then 'EVERYTHING LOOKS OK HERE.'
                Else 'PLEASE CHECK THE SCHEDULER FOR THIS FEED.' END as    "VERIFICATION_NOTE"
from
        ( 
            select 
                    UPPER(ds."schema_name") as "schema_name", UPPER(ds."table_name") as "table_name", ds."bundle" as "bundle_name", ds."text_file" as "text_file", 
                    ds."sequence" as "sequence_no", TO_DATE(s2.end_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') as lastupdateapplied, TO_DATE(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') as "next_sat_date",  
                    TO_DATE(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY')-(INTERVAL '7' DAY + INTERVAL '1' SECOND),'DD-MM-YYYY') AS "prev_sat_date"
            from FDS_FDS_DATA_SEQUENCES ds 
            Join 
            (   select "table_name", "bundle", "text_file", max("end_time") as end_time 
                from FDS_FDS_FILE_HISTORY 
                where "file_type" = 'full' 
                group by "table_name", "bundle", "text_file") s 
             on s."bundle" = ds."bundle" and s."table_name" = ds."table_name" and s."text_file" = ds."text_file"
            Join 
            (   select "table_name", "bundle", "text_file", max("end_time") as end_time 
                from FDS_FDS_FILE_HISTORY 
                where "file_type" = 'update' 
                group by "table_name", "bundle", "text_file") s2 
            on s2."bundle" = ds."bundle" and s2."table_name" =  ds."table_name" and s2."text_file" = ds."text_file" 
Order by 
            ds."schema_name" asc, ds."bundle" asc, s2.end_time desc )
```

Expected result is i should not get the error and actual result is ===>when i run the same query in ORACLE SQL Developer it runs perfectly but does not run in excel VBA module.

Comment: It seems you are just copying your Jira ticket into Stack overflow. We are not here to do your work though, if you have a specific problem, we are here to help though.

Comment: David thanks for the comment. I have seen the other questions on the forum but i was facing error in different situation. That was the only reason I posted the question. Hope this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> despite of using to_date function

Actually it's *because of* using the `to_date()` function. You have things like this:

```
TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY')
TO_DATE(s2.end_time,'DD-MM-YYYY')
TO_DATE(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
TO_DATE(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY')-(INTERVAL '7' DAY + INTERVAL '1' SECOND),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

The second of those *might* be OK, but only if `sd.end_time` is stored as a string - which it almost certainly shouldn't be.

For the other three, at least, you're passing something *that is already a date* into a function that is there to convert from a string to a date. So you're really doing, for example:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

and as that implicit `TO_CHAR()` doesn't have a format model it will use your session's NLS settings, specifically `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. You're seeing it work in one environment because the settings there effectively mean it's doing:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

whereas in another session it might effectively be doing:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-RR'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

... which would lose the century, leaving a date value in year 0019 instead of 2019; or

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

which throws "ORA-01861: literal does not match format string" as you are seeing.

While you could try to force the NLS settings on every client and application to match what you're doing it'll go wrong eventually, and you should be doing that conversion at all. Just use `SYSDATE` and other calculated directly instead; or if you're trying to get the dates with the times set to midnight truncate them:

```
trunc(SYSDATE)
trunc(s2.end_time)
trunc(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY'))
trunc(next_day(SYSDATE,'SATURDAY')-(INTERVAL '7' DAY + INTERVAL '1' SECOND))
```

Also note that the second argument to `next_day()` is the day name or abbreviation in the current session date language, so someone running this from a session in a different language will also see errors (like "ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week").

Comment: Alex Poole Thanks a lot that solved my problem. This would help others too.